# Question about using jschat gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having some trouble getting this running.

http://github.com/alexyoung/jschat

I ran:

jschat-server

jschat-web

and was able to access the page on localhost:4567
However after I entered a name and chatroom I got this error:

INFO -- :  (): {"cookie":"pl5n6xsu"}
Data that raised exception: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
"{\"identify\":\"sean\",\"cookie\":\"pl5n6xsu\",\"session_length\":null,\"ip\":\"127.0.0.1\"}"
Stack:
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jschat-0.3.3/lib/jschat/server.rb:576:in `each'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jschat-0.3.3/lib/jschat/server.rb:576:in`print_call_stack'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jschat-0.3.3/lib/jschat/server.rb:571:in `receive_line'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/protocols/linetext2.rb:64:in`receive_data'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in`run'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jschat-0.3.3/lib/jschat/server.rb:39:in `run!'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jschat-0.3.3/bin/jschat-server:7
 /usr/bin/jschat-server:19:in`load'
 /usr/bin/jschat-server:19

I am not sure if I am running this correctly as there are some other usage instructions as well that I am not sure how to use.  It says the web app must be started in production mode: http/jschat.rb -e production  .  Where do I run that command?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I've been looking into this project lately myself.  Does anyone know if this can be setup to run on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the json gem(a dependency) does not work with jschat.  I installed json gem 1.1.9 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU for posting this! I was stuck on this today, too. I did a gem install json -v 1.1.9 and gem uninstall -v 1.4.6 and i was in business.